# Convert array values to an array

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to effectively convert the values of this array from a string to array. I really appreciate any suggestion.

```
    array(6) {
  ["A"]=>
  string(31) "['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],"
  ["B"]=>
  string(41) "['A' => 3, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 7],"
  ["C"]=>
  string(51) "['A' => 5, 'B' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 6, 'F' => 3],"
  ["D"]=>
  string(51) "['A' => 9, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 2, 'E' => 2, 'F' => 2],"
  ["E"]=>
  string(41) "['B' => 7, 'C' => 6, 'D' => 2, 'F' => 5],"
  ["F"]=>
  string(31) "['C' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 5],"
}
```

Desired output:

```
    $graph = [
    'A' => ['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],
    'B' => ['A' => 3, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 7],
    'C' => ['A' => 5, 'B' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 6, 'F' => 3],
    'D' => ['A' => 9, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 2, 'E' => 2, 'F' => 2],
    'E' => ['B' => 7, 'C' => 6, 'D' => 2, 'F' => 5],
    'F' => ['C' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 5],
 ];
```

Comment: Please supply not only the input, but also the desired output. Saying "to an array" doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy, I have edited my post. I tried to use explode(), but I get undesirable results. Any tip, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to convert array string to an array.

You can repeat through loop or make function to get your desired output.

I'm using **regular expression** with **preg_match_all**

**Code**

```
$rawArray  =  array("A"=>"['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],",
    "B"=>"['A' => 3, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 7],",
    "C"=>"['A' => 5, 'B' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 6, 'F' => 3],",
    "D"=>"['A' => 9, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 2, 'E' => 2, 'F' => 2],",
    "E"=>"['B' => 7, 'C' => 6, 'D' => 2, 'F' => 5],",
    "F"=>"['C' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 5],",
);
foreach($rawArray as $k => $v){
preg_match_all("/\'(.)\'/", $v, $key);
preg_match_all("/=> (\d)/", $v, $val);
$graph[$k] = array_combine($key[1], $val[1]);
}
print_r($graph);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [B] => 3
            [C] => 5
            [D] => 9
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [A] => 3
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 4
            [E] => 7
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [A] => 5
            [B] => 3
            [D] => 2
            [E] => 6
            [F] => 3
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [A] => 9
            [B] => 4
            [C] => 2
            [E] => 2
            [F] => 2
        )

    [E] => Array
        (
            [B] => 7
            [C] => 6
            [D] => 2
            [F] => 5
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 2
            [E] => 5
        )

)
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/s2jIn)

**Explanation:**

1. **$rawArray** is associate array, each of it's element contain string similar to php array.
2. We're looping through array and converting that string to array by using **preg_match_all** and building **$graph** multidimension array.
3. When loop execute first time `$k` is equal to `A` and `$v` is equal to `['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],`
4. First **preg_match_all** make array of keys from **$v** (`['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],`), and assign it to `$key[1]`. Now `$key[1]` is array `['B', 'C', 'D']`.
5. Second **preg_match_all** make array of values from **$v** (['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],), and assign it to `$val[1]`. Now `$val[1]` is array `[2, 5, 9]`.
6. We're combining`$key[1]`as keys and `$val[1]` as values by using **array_combine** to the `$graph[$k]` where `$k` is `A`.

**How preg_match_all works?**

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $out);
```

It's matches pattern from string and then assign result to the `$out` as array.

Learn more about.
[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) 
[regex pattern cheat sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

**Note:** We're using non-capturing pattern so, it's return both exact match and desired match... So our desired record found in`$key[1]`.

Comment: Smartpal, I really appreciate your help. But what I mentioned above the desired output I neeed. I am trying to parse JSON with PHP. The original code is here, please check:  https://github.com/mestre-c/php2018/blob/master/dao-tech-task/graph.json

Comment: I was thinking along these lines. You can get the keys and values with just one preg_match_all, btw.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, we can by joining regex pattern together, but it's more easy to understand step-by-step!

Comment: Smartpal, one main point, just right after the foreach, I've converted the value ($v), which is an array to string by doing this:  $v = implode(",", $v);. By the way, Can you please explain the preg_math_all() methods? What exactly are they replacing?

Comment: @Capfer explained

Comment: Please note that a key value like `B\'c` would fail and be parsed as `c`. [Example](https://3v4l.org/3f5CV)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks for letting me know, This is suitable for OP, because there's no key like that in input string, or we can cover it with boundary for strict check. Thanks again.

Comment: @Smartpal Agreed; I think it should be OK for OP as well - there's no reason to write a custom lexer for this if OP can do with normal regex. It was just to point it out to OP _in case_.

Answer (score 1):

A little ugly but I think this finally does the trick.

I downloaded your **[file](https://github.com/mestre-c/php2018/blob/master/dao-tech-task/graph.json)** and ran this locally so that the source is exactly as you stated. Then I proceeded to parse it and convert the string value to an actual array

Here's how it looks now:

```
// Parse graph.json file
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('graph.json'), true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
        $str = str_replace(['[', ']'], '', $val);
        $str = str_replace(' => ', ',', $str);
        $str = str_replace("'", "", $str);
        $str = explode(',', $str);

        for ($x = 0; $x < count($str); $x = $x + 2) {
            $graph[$k][trim($str[$x])] = $str[$x+1];
        }
    }
}

// Result
echo "<pre>";
print_r($graph);

// Proof it is an array now (result 3)
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($graph['A']['B']);
```

Final Result:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [B] => 3
            [C] => 5
            [D] => 9
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [A] => 3
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 4
            [E] => 7
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [A] => 5
            [B] => 3
            [D] => 2
            [E] => 6
            [F] => 3
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [A] => 9
            [B] => 4
            [C] => 2
            [E] => 2
            [F] => 2
        )

    [E] => Array
        (
            [B] => 7
            [C] => 6
            [D] => 2
            [F] => 5
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 2
            [E] => 5
        )

)
```

If you run the below which is your expected output example and then compare the output to my output it is identical:

```
$graph = [
    'A' => ['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],
    'B' => ['A' => 3, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 7],
    'C' => ['A' => 5, 'B' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 6, 'F' => 3],
    'D' => ['A' => 9, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 2, 'E' => 2, 'F' => 2],
    'E' => ['B' => 7, 'C' => 6, 'D' => 2, 'F' => 5],
    'F' => ['C' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 5],
 ];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($graph);
```

Comment: dmotors, Thank you very much. Everything is working great. I've just seen your answer, so I had already voted above. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it,

```
<?php

$graph =  array("A"=>"['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9],",
    "B"=>"['A' => 3, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 7],",
    "C"=>"['A' => 5, 'B' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 6, 'F' => 3],",
    "D"=>"['A' => 9, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 2, 'E' => 2, 'F' => 2],",
    "E"=>"['B' => 7, 'C' => 6, 'D' => 2, 'F' => 5],",
    "F"=>"['C' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 5],",
);



foreach ($graph as $key => $value) {
  $val = str_replace("[","{",$value);
  $val = str_replace("]","}",$val);
  $val = str_replace("'",'"',$val);
  $val = str_replace("=>",":",$val);
  $val = rtrim($val, ',');

  $graph[$key] = json_decode($val, true);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($graph);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [B] => 3
            [C] => 5
            [D] => 9
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [A] => 3
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 4
            [E] => 7
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [A] => 5
            [B] => 3
            [D] => 2
            [E] => 6
            [F] => 3
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [A] => 9
            [B] => 4
            [C] => 2
            [E] => 2
            [F] => 2
        )

    [E] => Array
        (
            [B] => 7
            [C] => 6
            [D] => 2
            [F] => 5
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 2
            [E] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: thezeeshantariq, Thanks a lot. But if I do this way? my code is gonna break. Please plase, check the original gson file that I am trying to parse: https://github.com/mestre-c/php2018/blob/master/dao-tech-task/graph.json

Comment: I expect exactly the desired output above mentioned.

Comment: let me check, what I can do

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer is: don't create such a strange array ;) But since you did, this should do the trick:

```
//or $graph instead of $result
$result = array_map(function($value) {
    //use eval to directly evaluate the string
    //we just need to remove the trailing comma
    //and add a semicolon
    eval('$ret = '.rtrim($value,',').';');
    return($ret);
}, $array); // replace $array with the var name of your array!
```

But remember: eval is evil. If you don't trust the input you need to write your own parser.

Temporary edit for clarification. This is what I get when I run your github example trough `json_decode(...,true)`:

```
array(6) {
[0]=>
  array(1) {
  ["A"]=>
  string(30) "['B' => 3, 'C' => 5, 'D' => 9]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
  ["B"]=>
  string(40) "['A' => 3, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 7]"
  }
  [2]=>
   array(1) {
   ["C"]=>
     string(50) "['A' => 5, 'B' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 6, 'F' => 3]"
   }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
  ["D"]=>
  string(50) "['A' => 9, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 2, 'E' => 2, 'F' => 2]"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
  ["E"]=>
   string(40) "['B' => 7, 'C' => 6, 'D' => 2, 'F' => 5]"
  }
   [5]=>
 array(1) {
  ["F"]=>
   string(30) "['C' => 3, 'D' => 2, 'E' => 5]"
  }
  }
```

This differs from your question.

Comment: jh1711, thanks. I am getting some warnings: Warning: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given;    syntax error, unexpected ';' : eval()'d code

Comment: Strange. I used this script to test: https://3v4l.org/Z4m56. And the input seems to be identical to your array.

Comment: @Capfer, could you please run `array_map('var_dump',$array);`, and confirm/deny that it looks similar to the output in your question (just without the array keys). The `rtrim` warning baffles me.

Comment: Just a point! The keys are strings, and that's fine for me. But I need the convert the values to an array. I am trying to parse JSON with PHP. This is the original code on my GitHub: https://github.com/mestre-c/php2018/blob/master/dao-tech-task/graph.json

Comment: @Capfer, I added the (poorly formatted) output I get from your github.

Comment: @Capfer, You need to copy the full url. Yours shows up empty

Comment: @Capfer, nope it's still empty. But I'm off to bed anyhow. Check out the other answers. Some of the look promising; especially if you want to parse JSON, or something close to JSON.